# Can PyEphem find zenith times for specific constellation?

Tags: pyephem

Hi PyEphem developers.

I've checked the documentation but cause of me is not astronomy specialist I was unable to find and answer, do PyEphem can help me to find a time when specific constellation is in its zenith position for specific date and place on Earth? I need to calculate times for entire year…

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are looking for transit time
see the pyephem doc here

http://rhodesmill.org/pyephem/rise-set.html#

Comment: Thank you very much, I've succeed in my purpose. Only question remains is where I can find a coordinates of the constellation if there is no any star of my constellation in PyEphem star catalog…

Answer (score 1):

the stars are catalogued  in the src directory in file
stars.py

you can add stars to the catalog see:    readdb  and note the caveats

http://rhodesmill.org/pyephem/tutorial.html#fixed-objects-precession-and-epochs